# Oracle DB - What tables are IOT?

Tags: oracle

I have an existing Oracle database. I would like to find out what tables are Index Organized Tables - not sure what column to use in the all_tables table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IOT_TYPE` column.

> If the table is an index-organized table, then `IOT_TYPE` is `IOT`,
>   `IOT_OVERFLOW`, or `IOT_MAPPING`. If the table is not an index-organized
>   table, then `IOT_TYPE` is `NULL`.

[Oracle docs for ALL_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D.htm#REFRN20286)